# Linear Difference Equations

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $g_1, g_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,5]}$ be defined by $g_1(x) = x$ and $g_2(x) = 1-x$ for each $x \in [0,5]$.

Find a second-order homogeneous linear difference equation on $[0,3]$ such that {$g_1, g_2 $} forms a fundamental set of solutions to that equation on$[0,3]$.

My work on this question:

I started with the general proof of this questions. Let me state the question and the proof I conducted to the general format. I believe it is easier to replicate through the general format.

Let $g_1, ..., g_n \in \mathbb{R}^{[a,b+n]}$ with the property that $\forall x \in [a,b] : C[g_1(x), ..., g_n(x) ] \neq 0 $, where a, b $\in \mathbb{R}$ with b - a $\ge$ n. construct n th order homogeneous linear difference equation on [a,b] such that {$g_1, ..., g_n $} is a fundamental set of solutions of this equation on [a,b], if possible.

$\mathbf{PROOF}$

Assume that $g_1, ..., g_n \in \mathbb{R}^{[a,b+n]}$ are such that $\forall x \in [a,b] $ : $C[g_1(x), ..., g_n(x) ] \neq 0 $. Now assume that y(x+n)+...+$p_1(x)$y(x+1) +$p_0(x)$y(x) = 0 such that $g_1, ..., g_n$ are all solutions of this equation on [a,b] in which case $g_1, ..., g_n$ will be a fundamental system of solutions. But then, we have, for each x $\in$ [a,b], $p_0(x)g_1(x)+...+p_{n-1}(x)g_1(x+n-1)= - g_1(x+n)$,
$p_0(x)g_n(x)+...+p_{n-1}(x)g_n(x+n-1)= - g_n(x+n)$. But now, again for each $x \in [a,b]$, the determinant of the coefficient matrix of the above system is nothing but $C[g_1(x), ..., g_n(x) ] \neq 0 $.
So, one can solve the above sytem for $p_0(x)+...+p_{n-1}(x)$ in terms of $g_1, ..., g_n $, obtaining the desired n th order linear difference equation.

Comment: Thank you for your question.  We will be better able to help you if you share the context of this question, such as anything you are expected to use in its solution.  Please share your thoughts on the problem and anything you've tried so far, so that we don't duplicate your efforts.  Lastly, it is considered rude here to issue commands (e.g. "Find") rather than asking questions.

Comment: @vadim123 I was trying to stick with the orginal format of the question that is why I put find. I will be careful next time if it considered as rude. I will put some workings soon because I am still checking if I am on the right track.

Comment: @vadim123 I added some work you can check if it is better now.

Comment: Need an equation with characteristic equation that is divisible by $1 - r$ (for the $1 - x + x = 1$) and $(1 - r)^2$ (for the $x$). Simplest one is $a_{x + 2} - 2 a_{x + 1} + a_x = 0$